# Output (console) screen has disappeared in XCode?

Tags: xcode

Right, I don't know what just happened, the output screen's not showing on my XCode.

[image]

Comment: Don't worry got it, 'view , debug area, console'

Answer (score 3):

Select the 2nd option in the Upper Right Corner which reads as **View** and ur done:)

[image]